# azure in app mysql not starting

Tags: mysql, azure

I am new to Azure, For learning I created a new Web App + MySQL. I used MySQL In APP for DB.

Azure web app seem to start fine and I could see PHP process in the process explore. But I am not seeing mysqld.exe process in the process explore and PHPMyAdmin is taking me to login page. I am not seeing any logs for mysql either.

Please let me know if I am missing something ? Any help would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It can be glitchy, apparently, click around for a bit according to Microsoft and as long as the website is running then it should soon realise that its there.  Worked for me, see this link.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/09/08/troubleshooting-faq-for-mysql-in-apppreview/

Comment: this link is broken; does anyone know where to find this article...